How to only read the first row of XLSX file in JS
Alternate title can be how to extract column names from a xlsx file. Because that is my goal.
I want to extract the column names from xlsx files, I have written code for that but the problem is for larger files having > 10k records, It is taking a lot of time and even my page hangs and is unresponsive.
extractColumnsXlsx(file: File): Promise<string[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const arrayBuffer = event.target?.result;

      try {
        const workbook = XLSX.read(arrayBuffer, { type: 'array' });
        const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        console.log("First Sheet Name:", firstSheetName);

        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
        console.log("Worksheet:", worksheet);

        console.log("!ref Property ->", worksheet['!ref']);

        let columnNames: string[] = [];

        if (worksheet['!ref']) {
          const parts = worksheet['!ref'].split(':');
          console.log("First and Last Cells: ", parts);

          const refObj = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
          const firstColIndex = refObj.s.c;
          const lastColIndex = refObj.e.c;

          console.log("firstColIndex:", firstColIndex);
          console.log("lastColIndex:", lastColIndex);

          let firstRowData;
          try {
            firstRowData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
              header: 1,
              range: `${XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: firstColIndex, r: 0 })}:${XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: lastColIndex, r: 0 })}`,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error reading first row: ', error);
          }

          if (firstRowData && firstRowData.length) {
            columnNames = firstRowData[0]; // Assuming first row contains column names (index 0)
          } else {
            console.warn('Failed to read column names from first row.');
          }

          console.log('Column Names:', columnNames);
          resolve(columnNames);
        } else {
          console.error('Missing of invalid !ref property in worksheet!');
          reject(new Error('Missing !ref property in worksheet'));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    };

    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });
}


I was searching for some method to only read the first row from the xlsx file but couldn't find anything useful. Some one suggested using something like this
 const workbook = xlsx.readFile('path/to/your/file.xlsx', { sheetRows: 5 });

but I don't have the file path, I am taking file as an input from user using the input tag.

Check this answer, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594212/9695286

actually the op already passed the correct range to sheet_to_json .. it's just a bit cryptic because used a template string literal.. by the way I think the problem is related with the fact you are reading the entire content upfront with readAsArrayBuffer and that's the culprit of endless wait. I'm afraid you'll hardly find an answer here because the whole scenario is hidden except the sole function. For example you never cited that you are using sheetJS and it maybe was going to help writing it somewhere (that's why I added that on tags)

yep exactly, I implemented this because its much more concise than mine. But its taking the same amount of time. because readAsArrayBuffer reads the whole file having > 10k records.
